# jQuery plugin that turns an ordinary table into a orderable table?

Tags: jquery, sorting, plugins, html-table

I have a regular HTML table. Is there a jQuery plugin that would let me convert that into something more, specifically being able to order the rows on any column?

Something like:

```
$('table.real_estate_values').awesomeTablePlugin();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the best plug in for me.. [Datatables](http://www.datatables.net/)!!